# Profiling OpenCL Kernels on Linuix

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, ethminer, gpu, linux

I'm trying to carry out some reasarch on the performance of Ethminer, specifcally I'm looking to get data for any OpenCL kernels that are created during the mining process.

I'm trying to assess the number of kernels created, how long they run for, when the are created etc, Generally at this point I'm just trying to gather as much information about them as I can get during runtime.

Having looked at the Ethminer docs and source, I can't see any options for profiling.

So is there any way using the geth/ccp-eth clients and ethminer that I can enable any sort of profiling for the application?

If not are there any recommendations for tools / methods for carrying out this profiling?

Comment: AMD has a [APP SDK](https://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) available for Linux and Windows, but I've only used profiling tools on Windows. But you need an AMD graphic card to profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used this tool but here is a link to an OpenCL profiling tool I am aware of.  The project has had no updates for over a year but there are recent issues that have been submitted in the last 6 months including one from about 30 days ago.  The developer appears to be responsive still responding to comments the same day.

https://github.com/LTPV/LTPV